# Why I get error "Your security settings have blocked a local application from running”?

Tags: java, security, web

What you do to get rid of this? I wanted to make a game that is accessible from browser. Then I get error "Your security settings have blocked a local application from running".

I changed browser. nothing.
I added exception in "configure java". Nothing.
I looked internet and looked for "medium" security level but it was removed..

Comment: Your firewall is blocking the java service

Comment: @Dazak No I dont have a firewall

Comment: Short answer is *Who knows?* Now seriously, how is your app packaged?
 How is your app supposed to be launched? Did you try with several browsers or just a single one? Platform? Java version? Is this message a Java alert or a browser alert? Or maybe OS message? All these questions should be answered in your own question so people can actually help you. As is we can only guess: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It sounds like the applet you have asked for some privileges applets shouldn't have. Recently Java has been really strict onto what applets can do with your computer and what they can't. Again, java might have a security setting that will allow you to increase what an applet can do, but I'm not sure if they make that available in newer java versions. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html might have some info for you.

Comment: @FrznFlms But I noticed a lot of people have this problem yet no solution? Im not an individual

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'm not sure. But, I might know what's causing the problem. I'll list most of them here (you can find the full list at [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)):

> - Applets cannot access the local file system.
> - Applets cannot connect to or retrieve resources from a third party server.
> - Applets cannot load native libraries.
> - Applets cannot change the SecurityManager.
> - Applets cannot create a ClassLoader.
> - Applets cannot read certain system properties.

In summary, don't try to make changes to the user's desktop or the client's windows folder. Have them upload the file instead. Don't try to access .pngs or .json from external servers like google or yahoo either, probably because java can't guarantee them to be safe too. Neither can you load native libraries, so you might want to avoid those if you can, and finally you don't have access to some info in SecurityManager, ClassLoader or some System Props.

If your app violates one of these, Java is likely blocking your app from running. But it all depends on your implementation too. Make sure your browser doesn't block certain applet features (and that java supports your browser, make sure everything is [enabled](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml) too) and try again.

Or, you can ignore all of that and try making your app [privileged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html). Unfortunately I have very little experience with the process of making your app privileged, but from what I can hear, it'll give your applet a little more room to move in.

Comment: Not sure which are native libraries. I have a MP3 file inside jar but I dont think its that

Comment: Native libraries usually have a different build (.jar) you have to load at runtime. Watch out for those.

Comment: Hey, I just modified my answer to include a link to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html . There, you can learn how to request privileges from the user. Try requesting certain things you think your app might be violating (or just request everything). I hope the process isn't too complicated.

Comment: unfortunatelly people negged my question and i cant give you +1 Frzn:(

Comment: What's most important here is if it works. If it doesn't, than I can still look into it and edit my answer. Was anything fixed or is it still giving you the issue?